# Make animation rich dashboard with charts in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create some animation rich charts in a dashboard, I have attached some images on how I want,

[image]

Where onclick of pie chart section,  that section gets separated, and with loader animation, like its loading pie chart.

[image]

Some beautiful barchart with loader animation and such.

Before I used react-chartjs-2 library and I was able to build basic dashboard, but I was very static and I was unable add animations as such. If anyone could suggest me some libraries, that is rich in animation or some sample dashboard that includes these features.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Victory Charts (https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/), I've used them in the past for react native projects and loved the API, but it's really a web charts library (the mobile version has performance issues).

Comment: Could please share some sample dashboard where asked animation has been applied?

Comment: There are some examples here that show events, transitions, and animations, should give you a good start? https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery

Comment: This may be closer to what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/1wvx898lx4